# How to Union 3 dataframes by Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I need to union 3 dataframes df1, df2, df3, how can I:keep all columns in all 3 dataframes without overlab?

3 dataframes are for 3 different kind of products, one dataframe has less columns than the other two.

```
step1 = pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2)
all_lob = pd.merge_ordered(step1, df3)
```

The result seems eliminated some columns, how can i just stack 3 dataframes all together?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but when we are talking about putting the dataframes together on the column-level, you can use the pandas concat method and correspondingly specify the axis:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':[1,2,3], 'Col_2':[4,5,6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':[1,2,3,4], 'Col_2':[4,5,6,7]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Col_2':[4,5,6,7,8]})

df = pd.concat([df_1,df_2,df_3],axis=1)
print(df)
```